# Pinch to Zoom Google Maps API v3 Android Webkit

Tags: android, maps, webkit, pinch

I am writing a webkit app, and i'm using google maps api v3. I tried it on a android phone (HTC Desire) but it dosen't pinch to zoom. Note, i don't want to pinch and zoom a web page I want to pinch to zoom a google map v3 map in a web view. Has anyone got this working on android?

Comment: please leave the status, that you are able to solve these issue or not..

Comment: works in tablet 3.2 - seems to be fixed in android op - pls confirm some one else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works in tablet 3.2 - Amazing  pinch to zoom on a map works ! just like ipad. Who would have thought that a new version of android would fix an issue - rather than creating another bug - requiring yet another work around. Android i rate your version control 2 stars out of 5 up from 1 well done..well ...better get back to fixing the incompatibilities in my other apps!

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that, currently, you cannot rely on being able to receive pinch-to-zoom events on Android browsers.  Here it is in the Android issue tracker:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11909