# How to enable pinch to zoom?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, pinchzoom

I have created a simple mobile app using Phonegap.
It contains a single HTML page, it opens perfectly on my mobile Android device but the pinch to zoom is not enabled.
I have tried to add several libraries and meta name but it doesn't seem to work.

The HTML page displays a Google Map with markers.
Here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="420">
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

       .labels {
     color: orange;
     background-color: black;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 50px;     
     border: 2px solid black;
     white-space: nowrap;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jquery-xml2json-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.xml2json.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
    <script>
var markers = [];
var map = null;

  $.get('Customers.xml', function(xml) {
      var jsonObj = $.xml2json(xml);
        $.each(jsonObj.Marker, function(){
            var stat = this.site_status == "Critical" ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png" : "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png";
                 var mark = {
                        title: this.title,
                        location: this.site_location,
                        icon: stat
                        }
                markers.push(mark);
        });
        for(var i=0; i< markers.length; i++){
          var maddress = markers[i].location;
          var image = markers[i].icon;
          var custname = markers[i].title;
          geocodeAddress(maddress, image, custname,map); 
        } 
});     

function geocodeAddress(maddress, image, custname,map) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': maddress}, function(results, status) { 
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {   
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
      var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
      position: myLatlng, map:map, icon: image,labelContent: custname,
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}});
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

function initialize() {
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(35.442579,-40.895920);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: chicago,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What should I add in order to enable 'pinch to zoom' ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to have pintch to zoom you have to create a google.maps.event with "click" or "doubleclick". you can attach this event on marker you created or on entire map. tell me if you need some example and to what you want to attach your event or search for goggle map events. there are literally 1000000 of examples online.

Here is a simple example from google map site: [Simple click event in google map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple)

Comment: How exactly does adding a click event fix pinch to zoom?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `user-scalable=no` from your html head section

Comment: Now I understand that I've problably misunderstood your question. Are you trying to zoom the map or the whole html page?

Comment: I try to zoom the map

Comment: In this case, please ignore my answer as the issue is unrelated to the viewport meta tag. Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166432/pinch-to-zoom-google-maps-api-v3-android-webkit

Comment: The link reference they give there is broken.
Thanks for you're help !